# Moving item using in Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

Is there a way to move item using ID in powershell.

I know there is a way to Move item using path

```
 Move-Item -Path $_.ItemPath -Destination $destinationContainer;
```

But in my scenario, the path is same for multiple forms, so I would need to move item via ID.

Is this something possible via powershell?

Comment: Consider checking out the spe docs here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use ID for both source and destination. So the query will be something like this.

```
$itemID = "{8A87AC2B-210D-49F2-93FC-215918085418}" # Mention your Item ID to move
$desinationParentID = "{F0C8DEC1-75FB-4633-BA98-71CCD91F18F1}" # Mention your Parent Item ID where to move

Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "$itemID" | Move-Item -Destination "master:$desinationParentID"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can actually pass in the ID of the item instead of the string path.

```
Move-Item -Path $_.ID -Destination $destinationContainer;
```

So, `$_.ID` instead of `$_.ItemPath`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to get item first

```bsh
Get-Item . -ID $itemID | Move-Item -Destination $destinationContainer
```

If you are not sure if something is possible with given cmdlet run

`Get-Help Move-Item`

or find examples in the [documentation](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#move-item-to-a-new-destination)